# How to do a lucene search of "3.5mm"?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

When I do a BooleanQuery search for the term "3.5mm" I don't get any search results. The "." is not a special character so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Is there an easy fix?

I am able to find the search term if I use a wildcard token i.e. 3*5mm, but of course that will return lots of unwanted results too.

```
                innerQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            foreach (string term in terms)
            {
                innerQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(field, term)), Occur.MUST);
            }

            var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, searchFields, analyzer);
        IEnumerable<ScoreDoc> hits = indexSearcher.Search(booleanQuery, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
        IEnumerable<T> results = MapLuceneToDataList(hits, indexSearcher);
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: did you check that "3.5mm" content is indexed or not? and put your code example that what you try for?